# MySQL: Intermittant com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am getting this exception intermittently and am having a really hard time tracking down how to fix it.

The load on this server is pretty low, and the application is on the same host as the MySQL server connecting via localhost (MySQL 5.6). I have reasonable values for 'connect_timeout' (10), "interactive_timeout' (28800) and 'wait_timeout' (28800) and there is no firewall to cause issues.

Yet every so often this error pops up:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor206.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3414)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4874)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2431)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2882)
```

This is what I have for my Hibernate configuration:

```
   .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate")
      .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect")
      .setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider")
      .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "1000")
      .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "1")
      .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20")
      .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "1800")
      .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50")
      .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces", "true")
      .setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout", "20")
```

And this is my MySQL config:

```
[mysqld]

## General
ignore-db-dir                        = lost+found
datadir                              = /var/lib/mysql
socket                               = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
tmpdir                               = /var/lib/mysqltmp

## Cache
table-definition-cache               = 4096
table-open-cache                     = 4096
#table-open-cache-instances          = 1
#thread-cache-size                   = 16
#query-cache-size                    = 32M
#query-cache-type                    = 1

## Per-thread Buffers
#join-buffer-size                    = 512K
#read-buffer-size                    = 512K
#read-rnd-buffer-size                = 512K
#sort-buffer-size                    = 512K

## Temp Tables
#max-heap-table-size                 = 64M
#tmp-table-size                      = 32M

## Networking
#interactive-timeout                 = 3600
max-connections                      = 400
max-connect-errors                   = 1000000
max-allowed-packet                   = 16M
skip-name-resolve
wait-timeout                         = 600

## MyISAM
key-buffer-size                      = 32M
#myisam-recover                      = FORCE,BACKUP
myisam-sort-buffer-size              = 128M

## InnoDB
#innodb-buffer-pool-size             = 256M
innodb-file-format                   = Barracuda
#innodb-file-per-table               = 1
#innodb-flush-method                 = O_DIRECT
#innodb-log-file-size                = 128M

## Replication and PITR
#binlog-format                       = ROW
expire-logs-days                     = 7
#log-bin                             = /var/log/mysql/bin-log
#log-slave-updates                   = 1
#max-binlog-size                     = 128M
#read-only                           = 1
#relay-log                           = /var/log/mysql/relay-log
relay-log-space-limit                = 16G
server-id                            = 1

## Logging
#log-output                          = FILE
#log-slow-admin-statements
#log-slow-slave-statements
#log-warnings                        = 0
#long-query-time                     = 2
#slow-query-log                      = 1
#slow-query-log-file                 = /var/log/mysql/slow-log

[mysqld_safe]
log-error                            = /var/log/mysqld.log
#malloc-lib                          = /usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1
open-files-limit                     = 65535

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
```

Answer (score 0):

If load is low you can try to use `testConnectionOnCheckout` to true

testConnectionOnCheckout Must be set in c3p0.properties, C3P0 default: false
If set to true, an operation will be performed at every connection checkout to verify that the connection is valid.

Actually it's expensive.

A better choice is to verify connections periodically using c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod. Try to reduce the value and check how it works

Comment: Do you know if idelConnectionTestPeriod is the same as hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period. I have the later set to 1000